# How to return an object as a function?

Tags: node.js, function, object

I'm using module.exports to get the classes I need, in three of them I need to call the constructor before, but then they return an object instead of a function.

How can I make them return a function, so the classes can be used just like the others?

**Handlers.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
    Class: new (require("./Class"))(),
    OtherClass: require("./OtherClass"),
    ...
}
```

**index.js:**

```js
const handlers = require("../Handlers")

// This is called dynamically, which is why I'm using the module.exports
// handler is from a JSON object, let's say file is Class and event is a method within that class
handlers[handler.file][handler.event](data, arg2)
```

I want the first class to have the same type as the second class. Currently, the first is an object and the second a function. I have to pass parameters to the class, so it has to be a function.

**Output:** (console.log of the Handlers.js)

```
Class: Class { ... }
OtherClass: [Function: OtherClass]
```

Comment: If you call the constructor, you're given an instance (an object), not the original constructor (a function). It's not clear what exactly the issue is, but if you want to export a function, you'd have to use the constructor, and if you want to export an instance, it would necessarily be an object

Comment: @CertainPerformance It has to be a function, but I really need to call the constructor before returning it. Is there any way this can be made possible?

Comment: I guess you could return a function that, when called, returns the instance, but that sounds odd. A more detailed explanation of what you're trying to do might make the situation clearer, and a better answer might be possible

Comment: @CertainPerformance I try that the first class returns the same as the other classes. I'm calling them later and pass parameters to them, which does not seem to work with an object.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain? There's not enough code at the moment to understand the problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have edited the question as good as possible. Maybe you can now understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It turned out that the methods were not available because they are static. As a function, they must be static, otherwise they are not available, they may not be for objects. If there is no better solution, it will be alright for now.